# Use JavaScript Higher Order Functions to find an input between two numbers in an array

Tags: javascript, higher-order-functions

I'm trying to improve my JavaScript proficiency, so I built a tax calculator that calculates a Federal Progressive Tax, and it works to my liking.

However, the point of this exercise is to learn more about JavaScript. The concept I am now tackling is higher order functions. Experiencing some difficulties. There are some built-in higher order functions such as `forEach` and `sort` which I was thinking about implementing here, but don't know how to.

According to ECMA6, there is a new technique for utilizing higher order functions that uses the `=>` technique, but this too is a foreign concept to me.

**Ideally, we solve this problem without the messy for-loop I've created, and instead using a more problem-specific higher order custom or prototype function.**

The same problem listed below can be found on my CodePen here for easier manipulation:
http://codepen.io/trevorwhealy/pen/EPzreJ?editors=0010

```
var singleBracket = [9275, 37650, 91150, 190150, 413350, 415050, Infinity];
var singlePercent = [0.1, 0.15, 0.25, 0.28, 0.33, 0.35, 0.396]; 

var taxes=0;

var salaryInput = 60000;

var lowestPercent = singlePercent[0];
var highestPercent = singlePercent[singlePercent.length-1];
var lowestAmount = singleBracket[0];
var highestAmount = singleBracket[singleBracket.length-2];

for(var i=0; i<singleBracket.length; i++){

  if(salaryInput < lowestAmount){ 
      taxes+=(salaryInput*lowestPercent);
      console.log(taxes);
  }

  else if(salaryInput > singleBracket[i] && salaryInput < singleBracket[i+1]){
    taxes+=(salaryInput-singleBracket[i])*singlePercent[i+1]; 

    for(var check = i; check>0; check--){
      var progressiveTax = (singleBracket[check]-singleBracket[check-1])*singlePercent[check];
      taxes+=progressiveTax;
    }

    taxes+=lowestAmount*lowestPercent;
    console.log(taxes);
  }
}
```

Thanks for any help you can provide, it's tough learning this on my own, and any guidance on the topic of higher order functions is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Not certain what Question is ? What is expected result ?

Comment: I suggest you start by replacing one of your for loops with forEach(). Have a look at the examples at [MDN's `forEach()` page](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach).   *"According to ECMA6, there is a new technique for utilizing higher order functions that uses the => technique"* - Using => is a way of defining a function, it's not specifically for use with higher order functions (though it is useful there). Just ignore that for now.

Comment: thanks @nnnnnn I'll look into it

Comment: @guest271314 I thought it might get lost in the text so I bolded it: Ideally, we solve this problem without the messy for-loop I've created, and instead using a more problem-specific higher order custom or prototype function.

Comment: Just as an aside I would recommend you to not look at ES6 too much until you understand ES5 well enough. Indeed most of ES6 is just better syntax for things that you could already do, and will work the same way, as in ES5, so I think it's just more useless confusion. For example, `=>` is just a new syntax to define functions but they also have some subtle behavior changes that you don't care about *at all* for now. So yea, just learn good ES5 (higher order functions are used a lot even in ES5) and then in some months you'll understand ES6 way more easily and clearly.

Comment: @Trevor _"Ideally, we solve this problem without the messy for-loop I've created"_ What is "messy" ? `Array.prototype.forEach` is not "problem specific" ; both `for` loop and `Array.prototype.forEach` should return same results. Whether `for` loop or `Array.prototype.forEach` could be considered largely preference of author

Comment: @guest271314 that's good to know, thanks guest

Comment: @lleaff  I figured I'd just add that in case someone had a ES6 solution.